# broken memoization code

Tags: python, memoization

I have a series of numbers I need to find the sum of.  The value of the first iterative operation is 1, the second is 20.  Every iteration which follows then uses the previous result in the formula n * (n + 1) / 2, so the third iteration, say i03 = 20 * (20 + 1) / 2, and the fourth, i04 = i03 * (i03 + 1) / 2.  This continues until the 20th iteration of i20 = i19 * (i19 + 1) / 2.  I want to do this using memoization.  This is my code:

```
def outFun():
    def sumFun(squares, total = 0, CONST = 20):
        if squares > 2:
            total = sumFun(squares - 1) * int((sumFun(squares - 1) + 1) / 2)
        elif not squares - 2:
            total = CONST
        return total

    return 1 + sumFun(20)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have a lot of recursion, but no memoization.  Which is to say, somewhere you need to assign `_cache[inargs] = result` before returning it, then when calling, test for something like `if inargs in _cache: return cachedval`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I understand your problem: You have a formula `x_n = x_{n-1} * (x_{n-1} + 1)/2` with recursion base defined as `x_1 = 20` (or `x_2 = 20`? Not clear from your description). The most efficient way to solve the recursion is bottom-up approach, when you start with `x_1`, then calculate `x_2`, etc. Alternative is to use dynamic programming/memorization:

```
mem={}
def f(x):
    if x == 1:   # base case
        return 20
    if not x in mem:    # if we did not calculate it before - calculate
        mem[x] = f(x-1) * (f(x-1) +1) / 2
    return mem[x]   # otherwise return it

print f(1)    
print f(2)
print f(3)
```

prints

```
20
210
22155
```

`f(20)` is a little large to print, so I will print the number of digits in it:

```
print "number of digits: %s" % len(str(f(20)))

number of digits: 530115
```

The code took about 9 seconds to run on my desktop:

```
import timeit
mem={}
print "Execution time: %s" % timeit.Timer("len(str(f(20)))",
                            setup = "from __main__ import f").timeit(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

you're calling

```
sumFun(squares - 1)
```

twice!

Why not introduce a variable to store the result? Something like:

```
if squares > 2:
    nextResult = sumFun(squares - 1)
    total = nextResult * ((nextResult + 1) / 2)
```